# Reverse for 'new_entry' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['new_entry/(?P<topic_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new learning Django and I want a study tracker web app with Django. The error came up when I was creating the function and template for **new entries** - this will allow a user write a detailed note about a topic they are currently learning about but whenever I run the template I get an error message:

> Reverse for 'new_entry' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['new_entry/(?P[0-9]+)/$'].

I've tried looking at the latest new_entry() function I wrote and tweak the topic variable name but the did not solve the issue. I also cross checked my url paths for any misspelling or whitespaces but there isn't. Here are my project files.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'django_apps'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # Page that shows all topics.
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Detail page for a single topic.
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
    # Page for adding a new topic.
    path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    # Page for adding a new entry.
    path('new_entry/<int:topic_id>/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import Topic
from .forms import TopicForm, EntryForm


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    """The home page for django app."""
    return render(request, 'django_apps/index.html')


def topics(request):
    """Show all topic"""
    topics_list = Topic.objects.order_by('id')
    context = {'topics_list': topics_list}
    return render(request, 'django_apps/topics.html', context)


def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Get topic and all entries associated with it."""
    topic_list = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic_list.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic_list': topic_list, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'django_apps/topic.html', context)


def new_topic(request):
    """Add a new topic."""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = TopicForm()

    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('django_apps:topics')

    # Display a blank name or invalid form.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'django_apps/new_topic.html', context)


def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a topic."""
    topic_list = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        # NO data submitted; create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            latest_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            latest_entry.topic = topic_list
            latest_entry.save()
            return redirect('django_apps:topic', topic_id=topic_id)

    # Display a blank name or invalid form.
    context = {'topic_list': topic_list, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'django_apps/new_entry.html', context)
```

new_entry.html(updated!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Study Tracker - Entry</title>
</head>
<body>
{% extends 'django_apps/base.html' %}
{% block content %}

  {% for topic in topic_list %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'django_apps:topic' topic_id=topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>

    <p>Add a new entry:</p>
    <form action="{% url 'django_apps:new_entry' topic_id=topic.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button name="submit">Add entry</button>
    </form>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Base template</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <a href="{% url 'django_apps:index' %}">Study Tracker</a> -
    <a href="{% url 'django_apps:topics' %}">Topics</a>
</p>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Topic, Entry


class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A class that defines the form in which a user can enter in a topic."""

    class Meta:
        """This class tells django which model to base the form on and the
        fields to include in the form."""
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}


class EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A class that defines the form in which a user can fill in an entry to
    a topic."""

    class Meta:
        """This meta class tells django which model to base the form for
        entries on and the fields to include in the form."""
        model = Entry
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': 'Entry:'}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

I do not know how to go about fixing this issue. I've checked all my inheritance urls and templates for errors but I can't figure out what seems to the problem.

Update: Here is my topic.html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Study Tracker - Topic</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% extends 'django_apps/base.html' %}

        {% block content %}
        <p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>

        <p>Entries:</p>
        <p>
            <a href="{% url 'django_apps:new_entry' topic.id %}">Add new entry</a>
        </p>

        <ul>
            {% for entry in entries %}
            <li>
                <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
                <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
            </li>
            {% empty %}
            <li>There are currently no entries for this topic.</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endblock content %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I also checked the topic and entry ids in shell too.
[image: topic id shell checkup]

[image: entry, entry_id]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed your template *topic_list* variable but in your template you used *topic*. I think you would set a loop. Because you have no any variable named *topic*.  If you changed them, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the template of your `topics/<int:topic_id>/` view? (`django_apps/topic.html`)

To me, it looks like you have in this template a `{% url 'new_entry' %}` without specifying a `topic.id`. Because your path for this view is `'new_entry/<int:topic_id>/'`, the reverse url is failing and you see this error.

You probably want to change `{% url 'new_entry' %}` to `{% url 'new_entry' topic.id %}` or something like that.

Comment: `Reverse for 'new_entry' with arguments '('',)' not found.` suggests that something is wrong with your `topic.id`, is it set ? Empty string ? Did you display the value to check this ?

Comment: Yes I did. It's a dictionary

Comment: I just saw you added the template to your post.
You see `Reverse for 'new_entry' with arguments '('',)' not found.` because `topic.id` is not set in your context.
In your view, you are passing a `topic_list` :
`context = {'topic_list': topic_list, 'entries': entries}`

And you use `topic.id` in `django_apps/topic.html`.

You should rename `topic_list` to `topic` in `def topic(request, topic_id)`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be passing an empty variable to the template

```
    # Display a blank name or invalid form.
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form} # Change the context variable
    return render(request, 'django_apps/new_entry.html', context)
```

`new_entry.html`

```
...

{% block content %}
    <p><a href="{% url 'django_apps:topic' topic_id=topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a></p>

    <p>Add a new entry:</p>
    <form 
      action="{% url 'django_apps:new_entry' topic_id=topic.id %}" 
      method="post"
    >
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button name="submit">Add entry</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
...
```

Comment: @MrJPM you don't need `for`, you need to apply fix as @kamilyrb suggested in the first place.

Comment: Yes, in the view `def topic(request, topic_id):` `topic_list` is misnamed and isn't a list but a single element (`topic_list = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)`)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it mate change your view.py file
add the parameter topic_id to your new_entry field
and a topic variable with Topic object
and topic in context

```
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted, create a blank form
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted, Process Data.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry = form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.owner = request.user
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.save()
            return redirect('logemys:topic', topic_id=topic_id)
    # Display a blank or invalid form
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'logemys/new_entry.html', context)
```